# Friend template operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, operator-overloading, friend-function

The following program does not compile in MS Visual Studio 19.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class A;

template <typename T>
std::ostream &operator <<( std::ostream &, const A<T> & );

template <typename T>
class A
{
private:
    T x;

public:
    A( const T &x ) : x( x ) {}

    friend std::ostream &::operator <<( std::ostream &, const A<T> & );
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream &operator <<( std::ostream &os, const A<T> &a )
{
    return os << "a.x = " << a.x;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << A<std::string>( "Hello" ) << '\n';
}
```

The compiler says that operator << is not a function.

While the following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class A;

template <typename T>
std::ostream &f( std::ostream &, const A<T> & );

template <typename T>
class A
{
private:
    T x;

public:
    A( const T &x ) : x( x ) {}

    friend std::ostream &::f( std::ostream &, const A<T> & );
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream &f( std::ostream &os, const A<T> &a )
{
    return os << "a.x = " << a.x;
}

int main()
{
    f( std::cout, A<std::string>( "Hello" ) ) << '\n';
}
```

compiles successfully.

What is the reason of that the first program does not compile? Is it a bug of MS Visual Studio 19 or do I have missed something from the C++ 20 Standard?

According to the C++ 20 Standard (13.7.4 Friends)

> (1.3) — if the name of the friend is a qualified-id and a matching
> function template is found in the specified class or namespace, the
> friend declaration refers to the **deduced specialization** of that
> function template (13.10.2.6), otherwise,

Comment: Don't you need to declare the `operator<<` as a template too? Like: 
`template<typename U> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &, const A<U>&);`

Comment: @Ted That's it to my knowledge also (and always was), I am pretty sure that's a duplicate question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo As I understand each specialization of the class has the corresponding deduced specialization of the operator. See the second program that compiles.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Hmm... g++ fails to link both programs but clang++ compiles (and runs) both (all the way down to C++11)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I did neither - I'm searching for my life to figure out why they behave differently.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is not a duplicate question. Read the C++ Standard.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Does this beauty work? `friend std::ostream& ::operator<<<>( std::ostream &, const A&);` (it made g++ happy - but it seems msvc doesn't like it)

Comment: @TedLyngmo It is important that  there is used the qualified name of the operator that does not require template arguments. See the second program.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yeah, I can't really see why there is a difference between those programs. Tricky. Got my vote anyway :-)

Comment: Looks like a MSVC bug to me.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ... and in [g++ too](https://godbolt.org/z/r4PaaMT71) - The quoted paragraph doesn't seem to have changed since [c++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.friend#1.3) ... so, found no clues there.

Comment: Giving up for Tonight. The only version I found working with g++/clang++/MSVC was `friend std::ostream& operator<<<T>(std::ostream&, const A<T>&);` (or combinations down to `friend std::ostream& operator<<<>(std::ostream&, const A&);`) ... Looking forward to see where this ends up.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I know the standard to poorly but I was thinking: Isn't the name in the non-template declaration `friend std::ostream& operator<<<T>(std::ostream&, const A<T>&);` a qualified-id or have gotten that wrong? It doesn't explain the difference between how MSVC treats your `operator<<` and `f` (which bugs me), but still ...

Comment: @TedLyngmo No it is not a qualified-id. A qualified id looks like ::operator <<. So the compiler will search the name as it is already declared and if it finds a template function (and there is no non-template function with the same signature) it refers to the template function.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is defective; however there is indeed a bug (or two) in Visual Studio.

First, your `friend` declaration should be spelled with a `<>` to indicate that it is a template specialization that is the friend:

```
friend std::ostream &::operator <<<>( std::ostream &, const A<T> & );
//                                ^~
```

It is also acceptable to spell it with `T` explicitly (i.e. not inferring the template arguments):

```
friend std::ostream &::operator <<<T>( std::ostream &, const A<T> & );
//                                ^~~
```

Incidentally, gcc provides a helpful hint to make this change.

However MSVC will still erroneously reject the program; this appears to *only* happen templates of the specific `operator<<` where the class template argument is passed by reference, but not by value:

```
#include <iostream>
template<class> struct A;
template<class> struct B;
template<class T> std::ostream& f(std::ostream&, A<T>);
template<class T> std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, A<T>);
template<class T> std::ostream& f(std::ostream&, B<T> const&);
template<class T> std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, B<T> const&);
template<class T> struct A {
    friend std::ostream& ::f<T>(std::ostream&, A<T>);
    friend std::ostream& ::operator<<<T>(std::ostream&, A<T>);
};
template<class T> struct B {
    friend std::ostream& ::f<T>(std::ostream&, B<T> const&);
    friend std::ostream& ::operator<<<T>(std::ostream&, B<T> const&); // MSVC bug
};
template<class T> std::ostream& f(std::ostream& os, A<T>) { return os << "1"; }
template<class T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A<T>) { return os << "2"; }
template<class T> std::ostream& f(std::ostream& os, B<T> const&) { return os << "3"; }
template<class T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, B<T> const&) { return os << "4"; }
int main() {
    f(std::cout, A<int>()) << ' ' << A<int>() << '\n';
    f(std::cout, B<int>()) << ' ' << B<int>() << '\n';
}
```

The fact that MSVC rejects *only* `friend std::ostream& ::operator<<<T>(std::ostream&, B<T> const&)` makes it clear that this is a compiler bug. gcc and clang accept and print `1 2\n3 4`, as expected.

Another, similar defect in MSVC is that it will reject `friend std::ostream& ::f<>(std::ostream&, A)` (that is, using the injected-class-name to name `A<T>`).

Regarding the Standard, the language was changed substantially post-C++20 by [P1787R6: Declarations and where to find them](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html); in particular, it [removes](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/c7e8927098ab5074491edb64cbb4e1258c0c2141#diff-993d162d99c97390cfd9b2c9b076a5ef904d9e48366aa8bbbe7663cfc8367588L2973) the language that you quote in your question. As such, I don't think you can use that as an argument for being allowed to omit the `<>` from the friend function template specialization declaration, since P1787R6 resolves a bunch of CWG DRs and so can be regarded as a post-publication correction.

Comment: Reread the quote from the C++ Standard I provided in my question.

Comment: What you are showing is described in other quote from the C++ 20 Standard " (1.1) — if the name of the friend is a qualified or unqualified template-id, the friend declaration refers to a
specialization of a function template, otherwise,"

Comment: @VladfromMoscow that numbered list is removed from the Standard post-C++20, as per the diff to which I linked.

Comment: AFAIK this list is present in the C++ 17 Standard. So it looks strange  that 1) compilers behave differently and 2) the compatibility with the C++ 17 Standard is broken in  the C++ 20 Standard.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I don't think any compilers actually implemented C++ (03 through 20) in the way that you expect. So removing that list was a matter of bringing the Standard in line with implementation practice.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow interesting: this *only* happens to `operator<<` - every other operator is accepted by MSVC.

Comment: ah, I'm wrong - of course, MSVC did. So this is a case of implementation divergence, that hopefully will be resolved by MSVC fixing at least some of these issues.

Comment: Finally - your code is accepted by MSVC 19.22, rejected by 19.23. (per godbolt). So it's a recent bug, as well.